# Yahoo Finance YQL query not working. Did something change?

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

For the past year I have been able to use Yahoo YQL Rest query to obtain the currency exchange rates; however, today it has stopped working for some odd reason.

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.xchange+where+pair+in+(%22USDCAD%22)

https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22CADUSD%22%2C%20%22USDCAD%22%2C%20%22EURUSD%22%2C%20%22EURCAD%22%2C%20%22GBPUSD%22%2C%20%22GBPCAD%22)&diagnostics=false&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys

Has something changed? How can I find out what happened?

Is there an alternative solution I can use to obtain this data?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with http://datatables.org/ at the moment, which is the basis for the "Community Tables" (such as the Yahoo Finance table) on YQL. I haven't been able to find any more information on why it's down, but hopefully it comes back up soon.